# How to check for empty text field?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, string

I'm building a tool to generate a script of commands for integration purposes for some equipment using Java Swing. So basically the tool takes the user inputs in some text fields and then build the needed commands with the user variable.

At the end of my script I'm displaying the commands in a text area (`textOut`) by doing this:

```
command = "add user " + textUser.getText() + " Gender " + textGender.getText();
                textOut.setText(command);
```

This gives me a command like this:

```
add user Tom Gender Male
```

I've succeeded to have the tool running and giving the needed output commands in different lines, but now for example if the Gender field is optional and user left it empty, I want to also remove it from the output command because now if the field is empty it give this output:

```
add user Tom Gender
```

I want it to look like this

```
add user Tom
```

Any idea how can I do a check if a text field is empty (I found some ways to check if the value is null)? I also need to change the output command according to this.

Comment: I've just thought of a possible way but i feel it's a bit dummy :)
can i create different variables with the command fixed text and if the corresponding text field is empty i should set this variable to null 
like making a variable having the value "add user" the user didn't enter a name i can set this variable to null and output the variable and not the quoted text "add user"
is there a better way ?

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the Java solution (though your title says Javascript):

```
    final StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();

    command
        .append("add user ")
        .append(textUser.getText());

    final String gender = textGender.getText();

    if(gender != null && !gender.equals("")) {
        command
            .append(" Gender ")
            .append(gender);
    }

    textOut.setText(command.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Apache Commons [StringUtils.isEmpty()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)) to check if the `String` is empty

Answer (score 0):

Just make an `if` clause:

```
command = "add user " + textUser.getText();
if (!textUser.getText().equals(""))
    command += " Gender " + textGender.getText();

textOut.setText(command);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `textUser` is a `JTextField` you can check it like this `textUser.getText().isEmpty()` or  `(textUser.getText().length() == 0)`